# Throw away dirty copy-on-write pages

Tags: linux, mmap

Is there a way that I can create a copy-on-write mapping via MAP_PRIVATE, write some data (ie, dirtying some pages), and then discard my changes, *without* using munmap and re-mmaping?  The goal is to maintain the same virtual address for the given mapping (something not guaranteed to happen if I unmap & then mmap the same file again), but to discard all of my COW changes at once.

My understanding is that attempting to re-map the space via hinting the address and using the MAP_FIXED flag may have this effect; however I'm not sure if my interpretation of the MAP_FIXED docs is correct, or if this behaviour is guaranteed.

To quote from the mmap(2) docs:

```
If the memory region specified by addr and len overlaps pages of any existing
mapping(s), then the overlapped part of the existing mapping(s) will be 
discarded.
```

Does "discarded" in this case mean that any COW pages will be thrown away, and new reads from the corresponding pages will fault and reflect changes on disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you perform a `mmap` operation which overlaps with existing mappings, the Linux kernel will turf the overlapping part of the existing mappings as if an `unmap` had been done on them first. So for instance if you map a frame buffer where a shared library used to be, that memory now has nothing to do with the shared library; it points to the frame buffer.

The underlying page object from the removed mapping lives on independently of the mapping: pages are reference counted objects. When two maps share a view of the same page, it's simply due to the same page being "installed" in the different views.  When a page is made dirty, and then unmapped, this does not create a dependency whereby the dirty page must be written out prior to the new mapping; the virtual memory can already be re-assigned to a new mapping (such as a piece of a graphics frame buffer) before the original dirty page (for example, part of a file-backed shared mapping) is flushed out.

About throwing away a mapping: I don't think you can do this. That is to say, if you have a mapping which is supposed to flush dirty pages to an underlying file, you cannot write to that memory and then `unmap` it quickly (or `mmap` something over it) in hopes that the write is never done. In Linux's `madvise` API, there is `MAP_REMOVE` operation which seems relevant, but according to the manual page, it seems to only work on `tmpfs` and `shmfs`. I think the only way to block the write from happening would be to do the time-honored ritual known as "dive for the power switch".

There is a way to map a file object such that changes are not propagated: namely, `MAP_PRIVATE` (opposite to `MAP_SHARED`). `MAP_PRIVATE` is needed, for instance, by debuggers like `gdb` which need to be able to put a breakpoint into an executable or shared library, without throwing a trap instruction into every instance of that executable or library in every running process (and the copy on disk!).

If you have a `MAP_PRIVATE` with modified parts, and you unmap it (or those parts) or map something over top of them, I believe they will be discarded. Those pages should have been subject to copy-on-write, and so the process which made them dirty should hold the one and only reference. When they are unmapped, their refcount drops to zero and since they are private pages, they get turfed.

Comment: Very interesting.  So, if I 1) create a MAP_PRIVATE mapping over a file, 2) read it into the page cache, 3) dirty some pages via writes in that private, COW mapping, 4) re-mmap with the MAP_FIXED flag, overwriting the address space of the MAP_PRIVATE mapping, I should retain the underlying file's "real" data in the page cache, as well as throwing away my view of my COW "changes".  This is very handy behavior to have.

Comment: Bryce, yes; I believe the original data that is in the file should re-appear; the same data that you would see if you were to `lseek` to those locations and `read`.

Answer (score 1):

The virtual address remains the same even after the copy.  Only the physical address changes (and the associated memory mapping page registers).

After the process has written to the page, it is too late to undo it.  The copy occurs during the first write to the memory region.

Comment: I understand I will actually write to physical RAM on my first copy, and I can't "undo" it - but the question is whether a new mmap with an overlapping address (or some other mechanism) will result in that same virtual memory being "re-initialized" in a way that throws away those changes, from the perspective of the mapping process.